# Как найти индекс максимального элемента c++

Tags: c++, массивы

> Создать двумерный массив, состоящий из действительных чисел.
> Вычислить среднее арифметическое значение элементов главной и побочной
> диагоналей матрицы. Найти местоположение максимального элемента
> двумерного массива. Результат выведите на экран.

Как найти индекс максимального элемента ? Сам элемент нашел, спасибо

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int ROWS = 5;
    const int COLS = 5;

    float array[ROWS][COLS];

    float cross_right = 0; //Права діагональ
    float cross_left = 0; //Ліва діагональ

    float max_element = array[0][0];

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            cout << (array[i][j] = rand() % 10) << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) //Права діагональ
    {
        cross_right += array[i][i];
    }

    for (int i = 0, j = ROWS - 1; i < ROWS; i++, j--) //Ліва діагональ
    {
        cross_left += array[j][i];
    }

    float avarage = (cross_left + cross_right) / 2; //Середнє значення
    
    int indexI;
    int indexJ;

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            if (array[i][j] > max_element)
            {
                max_element = array[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    cout << cross_right << endl;
    cout << cross_left << endl;
    cout << avarage << endl;
    cout << max_element << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да просто

```
int indexI;
int indexJ;
....
max_element = array[i][j];
```

замените на

```
int indexI = 0;
int indexJ = 0;
....
max_element = array[indexI = i][indexJ = j];
```

И по окончании цикла будете иметь индексы...

Comment: Спасибо, поставлю галчоку через 9 минут, также записал indexI, indexJ, но не знал как присвоить значения, спасибо